# How to use abcpdf 10 annotations in Asp.Net c#?

Tags: c#

While executing these 
http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/4-examples/18-annotations.htm examples am getting errors, Can any one may tell what all namespaces i need to include in it.

```
using WebSupergoo.ABCpdf10;
Doc theDoc = new Doc();
InteractiveForm form = new InteractiveForm(theDoc);
theDoc.Pos.X = 40;
theDoc.Pos.Y = theDoc.MediaBox.Top - 40;
theDoc.AddText("Interactive Form annotations");
```

Comment: Could you include the errors you are getting, and the specific code which is causing them

Comment: The type or namespace name 'InteractiveForm' could not be found..missing directive or assembly refeence..this is an error i got..

Comment: It would be more useful to add this information to the question, rather than them being comments